# Odoo 12 - Working with default_foo global variable (res.config.settings)

Tags: settings, odoo, odoo-12

From various posts on this site, I have the following code (below separator) that works to create global variable. However, all online help like https://odoo-development.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/py/res.config.settings.html#default-xxx has TODO in howto for setting it.

*Part one* of question, is how do I set **default_paper_markup** from startup file referenced as data/pse_data.xml in manifest?I would like this set so any future imports could benefit from it.

*Part two* of question, is when I want to apply **default_paper_markup** in formula
*i.e.* total_price = total_cost * default_paper_markup?
Do I use default_paper_markup (since what I believe so for that default_* fields don't require get_value()/set_value() to retrieve/store) or do I use paper_markup from my module as being **the** global variable? The same goes for copying it to a field on estimate(like sales order) line item so it will become historical?

**UPDATE:** From https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/11.0/odoo/addons/base/res/res_config.py, "The method `default_get` retrieves values that reflect the current status of the fields like ***'default_XXX'***, 'group_XXX' and 'module_XXX'.  It also invokes all methods with a name that starts with 'get_default_'; such methods can be defined to provide current values for other fields." Would this mean I should write a `default_get(how?)` or `get_default_paper_markup(how?)` into a local variable prior to using it in a method performing a calculation? **/UPDATE**

*Part three* of question, as a side note, searching Odoo 12 CE for default_ in all res_config_settings.* returns nothing. Is this now deprecated or just unused? Should I not use it and just use functions? For example, using related field,search quotation_validity_days in the following: *addons/sale/models/*

---

*res_config_settings.py*

```
class ResConfigSettings(models.TransientModel):

    _inherit = 'res.config.settings'

    default_paper_markup = fields.Float(
        default_model='pse.paper'
    )
```

*res_config_settings_views.xml*

```
    <record id="res_config_settings_view_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">res.config.settings.view.form.inherit.pse</field>
        <field name="model">res.config.settings</field>
        <field name="priority" eval="70"/>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.res_config_settings_view_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//div[hasclass('settings')]" position="inside">
                <div class="app_settings_block" data-string="PSE Data-String" string="PSE" data-key="pse" groups="pse.group_pse_manager">
                    <h2>Paper</h2>
                    <div class="row mt16 o_settings_container">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 o_setting_box">
                            <div class="o_setting_right_pane">
                                <label for="default_paper_markup"/>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="text-muted col-lg-8">
                                        Markup of cost for reselling paper
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="content-group">
                                    <div class="mt16">
                                        <field name="default_paper_markup" class="o_light_label"/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>

    <record id="pse_config_settings_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Settings</field>
        <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
        <field name="res_model">res.config.settings</field>
        <field name="view_mode">form</field>
        <field name="target">inline</field>
        <field name="context">{'module' : 'pse'}</field>
    </record>

    <menuitem id="pse_menu_configuration"
        name="Settings"
        parent="menu_pse_configuration"
        sequence="0"
        action="pse_config_settings_action"
        groups="base.group_system"/>
</odoo>
```

*my_model.py*

```
    paper_markup = fields.Float(string='Markup')
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is working with the following updates. I went with the other route for now to keep moving forward. Will come back to this as I would still like to understand. So any **additional** answers would still be appreciated.

*res_config_settings.py*

```
class ResConfigSettings(models.TransientModel):
    _inherit = 'res.config.settings'

    paper_markup = fields.Float(
        string='Markup',
        digits=(2, 2),
        default=1.0
    )

    @api.multi
    def get_values(self):
        res = super(ResConfigSettings, self).get_values()
        res.update(
            paper_markup=float(self.env['ir.config_parameter'].sudo().get_param('pse.paper_markup'))
        )
        return res

    def set_values(self):
        super(ResConfigSettings, self).set_values()
        self.env['ir.config_parameter'].sudo().set_param('pse.paper_markup', Decimal(self.paper_markup))
```

*res_config_settings_views.xml*

```
...
<field name="paper_markup" class="o_light_label"/>
...
```

The following answers **part one** doing things this way. (remember to add to manifest)
*module_data.xml*

```
        <!-- Settings to enable -->
        <record id="config_pse_paper_markup" model="ir.config_parameter">
            <field name="key">pse.paper_markup</field>
            <field name="value">1.25</field>
        </record>
```

The following answers **part two** doing things this way.
*(module_name).py*

```
    markup = fields.Float(
        string='Cost Markup',
        help="The markup to be applied to the cost.",
        compute='_compute_markup',
        store=False
    )

    price1 = fields.Float(
        string='The Price',
        help="The resell price for paper.",
        compute='_compute_price1',
        store=False,
        inverse='_inverse_price1',
        search='_search_price1'
    )

    # ***** Compute and search fields, in the same order of fields declaration *****
    @api.multi
    def _compute_markup(self):
        for record in self:
            record.markup = float(self.env['ir.config_parameter'].sudo().get_param('pse.paper_markup'))

    @api.multi
    @api.depends('markup')
    def _compute_price1(self):
        for record in self:
            record.price1 = record.standard_price * record.markup
```

Comment: Sadly, that doesn't work anymore in Odoo 14. specially the @api.multi